New power supply resets every few hours - is this a faulty unit, or am I facing an usual failure mode?
I run a slightly unusual Xeon based build as a sort of compile/build/testing server. I'd initially tested it with a seasonic m12 620W. I'd wanted a fully modular PSU and picked up a thermalright TR-TPFX650. It runs fine - I've load tested it with both PSUs. My power usage for the entire system is ~175w but thats almost entirely CPU or through the motherboard .
 CPU Model          : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v4 @ 2.40GHz
 CPU Cores          : 28 @ 1197.103 MHz
 OS                 : Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS

System specs above - and its the same MATX-CS612 motherboard as this question
With the latter CPU - It resets somewhere between every 4 hours to 30 minutes, with the timing getting shorter and shorter. I 'start' again at around 4 hours if I leave the PC off, and this is fairly replicable. I'm only really aware the machine reboots cause it beeps when it reboots. There's a few quirks - there's no obvious logs to why it fails, cockpit shows the machine as rebooted.
I monitored temperatures and they never breach 50c - and the machine is stable with the other PSU. I'd also stress tested/thermal cycled the machine as part of the build process so I'm 99% certain the CPU is fine. I've had over a day of uptime on another PSU so I think we can rule out overheating.
I've fairly definitively isolated the issue to the PSU.
Last reboot shows multiple boots as being active - I suspect this is  due to an unclean boot
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Wed Dec 25 15:46 - 23:29  (07:42)
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Tue Dec 24 19:29 - 21:36  (02:07)
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Tue Dec 24 18:45 - 21:36  (02:51)
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Tue Dec 24 18:41 - 18:44  (00:03)
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Tue Dec 24 14:25 - 18:44  (04:19)
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Wed Dec 18 09:04 - 09:05  (00:01)
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Wed Dec 18 08:29 - 09:05  (00:35)
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Tue Dec 17 19:58 - 20:03  (00:04)

What I'm trying to figure out is if its a matter of the smaller PSU not behaving with the specific setup, or if I got a bum PSU. I've some ideas on testing the PSU on other systems with a lower wattage CPU, but I'm trying to understand what I'm looking at here, especially with the delayed, and shortening failure periods.

Does the server have a BMC (Baseboard Management Controller)? If so, this answer might help to get some information on the cause of reboots. Not sure the load test was, but in the past has uaed FIRESTARTER: A Processor Stress Test Utility

Its kinda wierd there - it has a AST 2500 as a GPU but no actual BMC functionality - its one of those chinese ones that repurposes old xeons as a desktop board.  - I tried the answer on AU and there's no /dev/ipmi0

This might not be important but what is the other CPU? While it’s never the intention of these Chinese motherboard manufacturers, it cannot be discounted, that there simply is a fundamental fault in its design. Unfortunately, ThermalTake does not have the greatest history, although my own has never had a problem. I assume you have tried applying in firmware updates to the board?

No firmware updates available. I honestly don't even know who makes the board - its labelled cloudstar but there's literally no presense outside two specific, and similar aliexpress matx boards. I've a 6th gen intel desktop system I have access to, and I might be rescuing a friend's old 4th gen core i5. In theory I could try running my main PC off this too. I'll be testing it on entirely different platforms though roughly contemporary or older

Also Thermalright, not thermaltake. This was a bit of a fun entirely aliexpress build. I've got a stable build for the motherboard - I'm trying to determine if its worth keeping the PSU as a working spare, repurpose it as a benchtop power supply, so to speak, or label it "wonky" and dump it in my spares box

I'd say bad power supply or gpu that is doing power excursions, except this would happen randomly.  The trend of shorter and shorter intervals between reboots makes me think your cpu is overheating, possibly because of bad contact with heatsink (poor application of heatsink compound) or bad cooler or something.  Note also there have been recalls on cpus that overheat, but I can't remember if this model was one of them.

CPU's fine on the other PSU so far. And there's no correlation between load and shutdown.  I switched to PTM7950 + it has a AIO that dumps heat directly out, and from what I can tell, the CPU never breaks 50c even at load.  Part of my build involved thermal cycling (which is recommended for PTM 7950 usage) - and I have trouble getting the system to 70+C at full load with my setup so I can rule out overheating of the CPU.
